# Add more test patterns to nosetests in python?

Tags: python, nosetests

So I have a directory named "test" inside which I have a few more directories, which have a lot of tests. How do I add such patterns so that nosetests determines these tests and runs it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run `nosetests` with option  `-i` `--include`:

```
-i REGEX, --include=REGEX
                      This regular expression will be applied to files,
                      directories, function names, and class names for a
                      chance to include additional tests that do not match
                      TESTMATCH.  Specify this option multiple times to add
                      more regular expressions [NOSE_INCLUDE]
```

Comment: Can we add a plugin or something? The same code is used by many people, so I want a solution so that we just need to run "nosetests" from the command line. Sure, I can ask everyone to add aliases and all, but I was hoping if there is a better solution.

Comment: Yes you can, you can use [code](https://github.com/nose-devs/nose/blob/master/nose/plugins/allmodules.py) of one of [bundled modules](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/allmodules.html) as example.